# Is there a way to make 2 <p> tags in a same line

Tags: html, css

````
 ```
 <p class='title'><em>WELCOME TO F-DRIVE</em></p>
 <p class='b'>Free 5GB storage space!</p>```
 ```
````

this is my line of code. I want both of these sentence to appear in the same line.
my css rules are:

````
```
p.b{
font-size:32px;
font-family: bangers, fantasy;
margin-left: 20px;
}
p.b2{
font-size:32px;
font-family: bangers, fantasy;
margin-right: 20px;
text-align:right;
```
````

the second one appears a line below the 1st, how do i fix it?

Comment: Do not try to bend an element that is supposed to render as a block to render inline. Use the correct element rather, which would be two `<span>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `span` instead of a `p` tag. `p` is a block element while `span` is an inline element.
You can find out more about the difference here: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/p-vs-span/5298

Comment: I used span and it comes inline but I want the 2nd sentence to go at the right side of the page but that doesnt happen even with css. Is there a fix?

Comment: instead of `text-align: right` try wrapping the 2 spans in a div and using `float: right` on the second span.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is `display: inline-block`, but if you want this kind of behaviour u should use `span` as span is inline element by default. It does not need any additional style

```css
p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
<p>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `<span>` for that matter.